# TestFlight for Enterprise Applications

Tags: ios, crash-reports, testflight

Ever since iOS 8, TestFlight has been integrated into the OS. If I'm distributing application using Enterprise Distribution Profile, how can I collect the crash reports?

Essentially, can we use TestFlight in our Enterprise applications? If so, how?

Note: I'm quite familiar with how we can use TestFlight for internal and external testing, using iTunes Connect. What I want to know is, whether we can integrate and use TestFlight if I'm distributing the application with-in the enterprise.

Comment: Was just thinking the same... Can't find apple once mentioning TF & Enterprise in the same sentence...

Comment: Seems that since the enterprise license doesn't give access to itunesconnect, you can't use that. However, you can still use the "old" testflightapp.com approch. Not sure though how long this will be possible...